# codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult() Hanging when Invoking a Lambda from VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

Update: 
After much trial and tribulation, I have determined that the code below [nodejs8.1 runtime], which is a basic CodePipeline setup with no additional code, works fine when one invokes a Lambda normally, but if one tries to invoke the Lambda from within a VPC, the `codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult()` hangs and the Lambda times out.  Any code that comes before the call runs fine, but it just won't run `codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult()` and give a proper return value back to CodePipeline despite both codepipeline and the Lambda having a role that has all kinds of policies and trust relationships and the VPC has lots of endpoints as well as a NAT Gateway and Internet Gateway.  This results in CodePipeline continually retrying until the timeout period (~15 minutes).

Note also that prior to adding the Lambda to CodePipeline and adding an endpoint that I was running the Lambda manually and successfully utilizing a static IP through a NAT => Internet Gateway (https://medium.com/@matthewleak/aws-lambda-functions-with-a-static-ip-89a3ada0b471) and again, even within the CodePipeline, the Lambda runs fine until it utilizes the AWS SDK `aws.CodePipeline.putJobSuccessResult()`/`aws.CodePipeline.putJobFailureResult()` functions; all other code is successfully executed.

In theory, to reproduce, one need only take the code below and create a Lambda, set up a VPC as described in the article above, set up a basic CodePipeline and invoke the Lambda as part of the pipeline.  The first run through should work fine.  Then assign the Lambda to the VPC and subnets, then run the pipeline again and see if it doesn't hang when it tries to putJobSuccessResult.

The hanging behavior implies it is a networking issue, but if CodePipeline has an endpoint to the VPC and successfully is able to invoke the Lambda, why would the Lambda not be able to talk back to CodePipeline to putJobSuccessResult/putJobFailureResult?  My guess is that either I'm missing something in terms of the VPC or CodePipeline isn't working correctly and/or utilizing its endpoint correctly -- but I'd like to figure it out.

```js
// Working Base response code for CodePipeline

'use strict';
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const codepipeline = new aws.CodePipeline();

let environment = 'dev';
let callback;
let context = {
    invokeid: ''
}

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    context = context;
    callback = callback;
    console.log('Inside deploy-website Lambda');
    if (!('CodePipeline.job' in event)) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    // Retrieve the Job ID from the Lambda action
    let jobId;
    if (event["CodePipeline.job"]) {
        jobId = event["CodePipeline.job"].id;

        // Retrieve the value of UserParameters from the Lambda action configuration in AWS CodePipeline, in this case the environment
        // to deploy to from this function
        environment = event["CodePipeline.job"].data.actionConfiguration.configuration.UserParameters || environment;
    }

    console.log(`Envrionment: ${environment}`);


    console.log('Copy Successful');
    console.log('Entering Results');
    return await putJobSuccess('Copy Successful', jobId);
}

// Notify AWS CodePipeline of a successful job
async function putJobSuccess(message, jobId) {
    console.log(`Post Job Success For JobID: ${jobId}`);
    const params = {
        jobId: jobId
    };
    console.log(`Job Success Params: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
    await codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult(params).promise();
    console.log('Job Success: Successfully reported hook results');
    return callback(null, 'Job Success: Successfully reported hook results');
}
```

Comment: Please include how your handler uses that code.

Comment: @dashmug Sorry, was in a hurry; I have updated it to include the handler.

Comment: Any reason for using the old API? You shouldn't be using `context.succeed/context.fail()` anymore using the latest NodeJS runtimes.

Comment: @dashmug I was just using the example off of the AWS docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html).  Do you have an example of how you think it should be done instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out it was indeed a networking issue.  It seems that the VPC route tables are what got me.  When you create a route table, it has you choose a name and a VPC to associate it to.  What I forgot to do was go to the subnets and associate them to the proper route table under the "Route Table" tab and/or I didn't choose the right one on one of them because when you choose a route table to associate it to, it doesn't show the logical name, just the route table ID, which makes it more prone to error.  So, while it was definitely a "Newb" mistake [so much pain from such a stupid mistake], I think there is something left to be desired in terms of user experience in associating route tables.

Answer (score 1):

With Lambda's Node 6/8 runtimes, it's easier if you use Promises (or even the `async/await` syntax).

The old `context.succeed()`/`context.fail()` syntax was for the old Node versions and those have been deprecated.

```
// Leave this outside your handler so you don't instantiate in every invocation.
const codepipeline = new aws.CodePipeline();

exports.handler = event => {

    if (!('CodePipeline.job' in event)) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    const jobId = event['CodePipeline.job'].id;

    const environment = event['CodePipeline.job'].data.actionConfiguration.configuration.UserParameters;

    return doStuff
        .then(() => putJobSuccess(message, jobId));
}


function putJobSuccess(message, jobId) {
    console.log('Post Job Success For JobID: '.concat(jobId));
    const params = {
        jobId: jobId
    };

    return codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult(params).promise()
        .then(() => {
            console.log(`Post Job Success Succeeded Message: ${message}`);

            return message;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(`Post Job Failure Message: ${message}`);

            throw err;
        });
}
```

Comment: I replicated what you put here and while the code looks a whole lot more like what I'm used to, it still didn't solve the fundamental problem, which is that `codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult()` refuses to function; I never see this console.log: `console.log(`Post Job Success Succeeded Message: ${message}`);`.  My role has "codepipeline:PutJobSuccessResult", "codepipeline:PutJobFailureResult", so not sure what is going on.